# Reproduce smb:// protocol syntax using pysmb

Tags: python, smb

I'm trying to use [pysmb](https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html) to save a file to a network share. In osx finder, I can log into the share by pressing `cmd+k` and then typing `smb://my.smb.url.com/folder/subfolder` and filling in the username/password.

I'm trying to list the contents of this same location using pysmb. This is what I have so far:

```py
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

conn = SMBConnection('username', 'password', 'name', 'my.smb.url.com', 
        sign_options=SMBConnection.SIGN_WHEN_REQUIRED, is_direct_tcp=True)
conn.connect('my.smb.url.com', 445)
shares = conn.listShares()
for s in shares:
    print(s.name)
```

I would expect 'folder' to be printed as one of the shares, since I am able to log into that folder with finder. However, it isn't one of the listed shares. The shares listed are:

```py
ADMIN$
C$
D$
IPC$
NETLOGON
SYSVOL
```

And the ones ending with $ don't seem to be readable (calling `conn.listPath('C$', '/')` throws an exception). Trying to list `/folder/subfolder` using `conn.listPath('folder', '/')` also throws an exception.

I'm trying to figure out how to map the `/folder/subfolder` in the smb connection string to the pysmb api. I have tried including the folder name directly in the `SMBConnection` constructor and within the call to connect, but the former doesn't change anything and the latter results in a "Name or service not known" exception.

Comment: `smb://my.smb.url.com/folder/subfolder` is incomplete. You need the share name as well.